# Drop can't be used in the generic struct implementing extended trait

Tags: rust, traits

> **TL;DR** https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99952dfdc8dab353992d2681de6b6f58
>
> **Full version** https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38d0c934cb7e55b868d73bd2dde94454

I don't quite understand why this doesn't work:

```
pub trait State {}
pub trait WithFinal: State {}
pub struct Machine<T: State> {
    pub state: T,
    error: Option<fn(&Event, &T)>,
    transition: Option<fn(&T, &T, Event)>, // fn(&current_state, &previous_state)
}

impl<T: WithFinal> Drop for Machine<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

```
   Compiling scdlang v0.1.0 (/home/wildan/Projects/OSS/scdlang)
error[E0367]: The requirement `T: statechart::WithFinal` is added only by the Drop impl.
  --> src/main.rs:92:5
   |
92 | /     impl<T: WithFinal> Drop for Machine<T> {
93 | |         fn drop(&mut self) {}
94 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
note: The same requirement must be part of the struct/enum definition
  --> src/main.rs:74:5
   |
74 | /     pub struct Machine<T: State> {
75 | |         pub state: T,
76 | |         error: Option<fn(&Event, &T)>,
77 | |         transition: Option<fn(&T, &T, Event)>, // fn(&current_state, &previous_state)
78 | |     }
   | |_____^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0367`.
error: Could not compile `scdlang`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I thought it should be working because `WithFinal` extend trait `State`

However, both these 2 `impl` work just fine:

```
trait DropLike {
    fn drop(&mut self);
}

impl<T: WithFinal> DropLike for Machine<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

impl<T: State> Drop for Machine<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

Comment: _"I thought it should be working because `WithFinal` extend trait `State`"_ In that case `WithFinal` is _more specific_ than `State`, so the parameter type `T` in that struct still needs to be explicitly constrained by `WithFinal`.

Comment: But if I constrain it with `WithFinal` then I can't use `WithInitial` 

Comment: There is no `WithInitial` in the actual question. Please provide a more accurate [mcve] (relevant code should not be behind a link).

Comment: `WithInitial` is on the **Full version** link  (I wonder if that's a rule in SO to not only link but also write down the full code )

Comment: Questions on Stackoverflow should in general not contain links to external code because links tend to become dead with time, making questions incomplete. However, to avoid questions becoming too big, code in the question should follow the rule of MCVE (which has been linked just above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you aren't allowed to implement `Drop` on specialized generic types.

Your `DropLike` trait is *like* `Drop`, but `Drop` is a language item, and gets special treatment from the compiler. This means this error only applies to `Drop`.

From the [Rustc Error Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0367):

> This code is not legal: it is not possible to specialize `Drop` to a subset of
>   implementations of a generic type. In order for this code to work, `MyStruct`
>   must also require that `T` implements `Foo`.

(Also visible with `rustc --explain E0367`)

Here's [the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/8142) that appears to have preciptated this change.

Comment: Thank you very much . So if I want to imply Drop I need to use `#[unsafe_destructor]`

Comment: @cimenx From the same source of that use of `#[unsafe_destructor]`: _"This is wrong."_  The attribute does not even exist in stable Rust.